# Cookie is not being set to the right Domain

Tags: reactjs, express, google-chrome, cookies, cross-browser

I am making a web app using **React and Express** but I am having a issue with cookies. React is running on localhost:3000 and express server is running on localhost:5500

I am sending the access and refresh token cookies from the Express server like this:-

```
res.cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken, {
  maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
  httpOnly: true,
  sameSite: "none",
  secure: true
});
// Sending Access token cookie to Client
res.cookie("accessToken", accessToken, {
  maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
  httpOnly: true,
  sameSite: "none",
  secure: true
});
```

But the cookie is being saved on the domain 127.0.0.1 rather than saving in localhost. That's why when I send the request after this the access and refresh token cookies are not being sent.

When I go to the server domain (localhost:5500) in the browser, I can see both of the cookies there but they are not visible at localhost:3000.

Note:- I have enabled withCredentials in axios as well and cookie parser also.

Comment: If the localhost is not using `https` then the cookies won't send because of the fact they have the `secure` option enabled. Have you tried changing `secure` to `false`?

Comment: Yes, I know that cookie is not using the secure option if the website is using HTTPS but I have read somewhere that localhost is a exception because no localhost is https secured! So, chrome allows developers to use secure with http.